# Image loading on page load

Tags: html, css, image, pageload

I have this htmls on a page which renders a photo album.

As you can see that there are 3 `<img>` tags.

The first two is under `<li>` which has display:none. But the last image is visible as it has style=''.

My question is: during page load will the first 2 images be loaded with the last image even if their container has display:none?

```
<div class="gallery">
                    <ul id="PhotoContainer">
                            <li style="display: none;" name="DSC01100.JPG" id="4ee01301602fdd0efc35683e">
                                <img src="http://site/Files/Get?fileId=4ee01306602fdd0efc356844"></li>
                            <li style="display: none;" name="DSC01102.JPG" id="4ee01308602fdd0efc35685f">
                                <img src="http://site/Files/Get?fileId=4ee0130a602fdd0efc356864"></li>                            
                            <li style="" name="DSC01101.JPG" id="4ee01306602fdd0efc35684f">
                                <img alt="my description for this image" src="http://site/Files/Get?fileId=4ee01308602fdd0efc356855"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why not to try it by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "loaded" you mean downloaded, then yes. **Resources with `display: none` styling are still fetched, just not rendered.** In fact, this is a valid image pre-loading technique, as discussed in this [article](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/06/14/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/).

To verify, you can load your page and look at the downloaded resources tab in Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which browser is loading the web page, I know google chrome loads all images, I expect most other browser are doing the same...

Answer (score 1):

All images will get loaded into the cache, and technically the webpage.  However, the css hides the 2 images before they come in contact with the human eye.